# Invalid postback or callback argument. When click on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am having a dropdown and two levels on my form and a submit button. When I select some value on drop down, my levels text updated with the selected value and selected text of dropdown.. but when I click on submit button, I get the invalid postback or callback argument exception...I m populating dropdown on client side using jquery ajax..
I have tried to use update panel..but doesnot work..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please provide code snippet which includes [mcve], exception details and relevant information to allow us examine your issue.